# How to execute code every time a Composable is shown (and execute only once)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a `Composable` which is responsible for showing notifications to users. Every time the user goes to that `Composable`, I want to execute a query which will clear the notification count. I only want to execute that query when the `Composable` has appeared, not every time the `Composable` is recomposed due to configuration change and anything.

Essentially I am looking for an equivalent of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onappear(perform:).

Is there any method I can use in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use LaunchedEffect ([link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect))

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    // Actions to perform when LaunchedEffect enters the Composition 
}
```

It takes one or more `key` parameters that are used to cancel the running effect and start a new one. Since you need to execute your code only once use something immutable as a key like `Unit` or `true`.